# Powershell - calling function in loops, variable initialisation and if statements

Tags: powershell, function

Like the title said, I have some trouble using functions in loops, variable initialisation and if statements as conditions. However, if I just call the fuction out of the blue it does work fine, leading me to think the problem is how I call the function and not the function itself, I may be wrong though.

Here's the function I'm trying to call :

```
function checkAlphaNumerical {
    param (
        #First, the string to validate, then a string to append to the error message
        $stringToValidate, $stringDesc
    )
    if ($stringToValidate -notmatch '^[a-z0-9]+$') {
        Write-Output ("Invalid $($stringDesc)")
        return $false
    }
    else {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Since I use `return $true` and `return $false` on both possible path of the function, Powershell console should output me `True` or `False` depending on the string value.

Here's the only scenario where calling the function works :

```
checkAlphaNumerical $testinput "test"
```

Here's three example where it does not work :

```
 do {
    $testinput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter string"
} while (!(checkAlphaNumerical $testinput "test"))
```

```
 if (checkAlphaNumerical $testinput "test") {
            #stuff
        }
```

```
$someBool = checkAlphaNumerical $testinput "test"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as expected because your function, as written, returns a two-element object array when your test is false:

```
PS > $TestFailure = checkAlphaNumerical '%' "FailTest"
PS > $TestFailure
Invalid FailTest
False
PS > $TestFailure.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS > $TestFailure[0]
Invalid FailTest
PS > $TestFailure[1]
False
PS > [bool]$TestFailure
True
PS keith>
```

And when the array is cast as a boolean, as it is when serving as a test conditon, it returns `$True`.

Changing `write-Output` to `Write-Warning` will display your "Invalid...." message at the console while ensuring the return value is simply `$False`. Also:

- In **PowerShell** functions, the `Return` statement is unnecessary. Any unconsumed output is returned.
- Since `$stringDesc` is simply a string variable, you don't need `"...$($stringDesc)"` in your expansion string.

So a working version of your fucntion would be:

```
function checkAlphaNumerical {
    param (
        #First, the string to validate, then a string to append to the error message
        $stringToValidate, $stringDesc
    )
    if ($stringToValidate -notmatch '^[a-z0-9]+$') {
        Write-Warning ("Invalid $stringDesc")
        $false
    }
    else {
        $true
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PS > do {
>>     $testinput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter string"
>> } while (!(checkAlphaNumerical $testinput "test"))
Enter string: '%'
WARNING: Invalid test
Enter string: '?'
WARNING: Invalid test
Enter string: abc
PS >
```